# Does “upshot” denote something positive, negative, or neutral?

Tags: meaning, nouns, connotation, nonsubjective

I’m a non-native speaker of English, and I’ve always felt that “upshot” was used to denote positive results. But I’ve come across a few cases recently where negative or neutral outcomes were enumerated after the use of “upshot”. For example,  “The upshot was that everyone got an incurable disease.”

Is “upshot” intended for positive outcomes only? Or mostly? If yes, what word is used for negative outcomes?

Comment: While I find this question interesting (without doing any research, I might've assumed _upshot_ was reserved for positive outcomes), the answer to your first question ("Is 'upshot' intended for positive outcomes only?") is [readily available](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/upshot). I suggest rewording it, as a recently learned statement, rather than posing it as a question, and then focusing on your second question (Is there a word that can be used for negative outcomes?) – lest this be closed as general reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although the "up" in the word may lead you to infer a positive connotation, technically "upshot" denotes an outcome with neither a positive nor negative connotation.

So it is equally valid to use the word for negative, positive and neutral outcomes.

"Upshot" is not to be confused with "upside," which is exclusively positive.

Such confusion does happen from time to time.  Here's one example, where someone wrote a comment using the word *upshot* instead of *upside*, to contrast with the later usage of *downside*:

> Its main upshot is that everyone knows their height and weight, and
> can quickly calculate a BMI, while the main downside is that you need
> a pretty typical frame with a typical fat-muscle-organ breakdown and
> whatnot.

*Its main upshot is..., while the main downside is...* is incorrect, since the writer is initially talking about an advantage, not a conclusion or end result.

<sub>Reference: Original post can be found [here](http://feministing.com/2009/05/04/i_want_you_to_stop_stalking_ov/comment-page-2/#comment-133059).</sub>

Comment: nice comment about "upside"

Comment: -1 for the unsubstantiated assertion that "technically" the word "upshot" is neutral. I don't think it's meaningful to talk about what words "technically" mean - they *actually* mean whatever people normally use them to mean. Per my answer, a quick survey of written usage clearly shows that the word is used far more often of negative than of positive outcomes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I must respectfully disagree with you. If we define "technically" to mean "according to the dictionary," then his assertion is entirely correct. Moreover, [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/upshot) returns several examples where the word is used positively, negatively, and neutrally, with no preponderance in any particular direction (e.g., "The upshot was a 221-point gain in the Dow Jones" & "the upshot is households have been backing down their debt and other financial obligations, but we still have … a mortgage problem"). Plus, your won/lost experiment isn't conclusive.

Comment: @J.R.: Dictionaries don't always give every nuance, and a handful of example usages in Wordnik don't really tell us anything. The examples given in my answer clearly indicate a very strong bias for *upshot* to be used in negative rather than positive contexts, and they involve thousands of written instances. It's possible yours and OP's personal experiences run counter to the norm, but I don't see how anyone could argue that the bias doesn't exist - or exists in the opposite direction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your insistence that upshot is generally negative is as erroneous as the idea that it's generally positive. You ran one experiment using the words "won" and "lost" - how is that "conclusive"? BTW, did you go to the Page 3 of your "473 instances"? **Very** interesting results on that page. Meanwhile, Wordnik gives me: _"The upshot was the formation of Amy's Army, a group of volunteers who have helped to find bone marrow donors for 23 people"_; that doesn't sound negative to me. I'm not saying the word is positive, but I'm agreeing with the dictionary: it can be used either way.

Comment: @J.R.: I know GB "estimated results" can be hopelessly inaccurate, but even the actual instances still show the bias I've claimed. Leafing through the first few pages of results for ["the upshot was that I"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the+upshot+was+that+I%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), it seems clear to me that where there's an obvious positive/negative implication, it's more often the latter. But I obviously can't convince you of that, so we'll have to leave it there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "_Where there's an obvious positive/negative implication, it's more often the latter_" - perhaps so, but my point is, how many of those citations have neither a positive nor a negative connotation?  Quite a few.  Which brings us to zooone said 13 hrs ago: "_Technically 'upshot' denotes an outcome with neither a positive nor negative connotation, so it is equally valid to use the word for both negative and positive outcomes_," never saying which was more *prevalent*, just that both were *valid*, which clearly they are, as is plainly shown with the link you just provided.

Comment: @Fumble: Thus far, the sentiment of the community is running 9 to 1 in favor of this being a good answer. If you were to reverse your vote, the upshot would be that our unfledged member would earn his first Good Answer badge, along with his first silver badge. :^) Care to have the honor? Or will we all just have to wait for a couple others to come along and tip the scales?

Comment: @J.R.: Point conceded. The bias is nowhere near as strong as I originally thought - and as you imply, even if it were to be *statistically* "significant", that doesn't make it *semantically* significant. I shall fall on my sword...

Answer (score 4):

My experience is of it being a synonym for *result* or *conclusion*, in British English and Business use.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Did you intend to place that comment elsewhere?  The excerpt doesn't contain 'upshot' and I don't see how it's relevant.

Answer (score 3):

What an interesting conversation this has been.  Well, the upshot is I've learned a lot about the word *upshot*.

The dictionary conglomerate [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=upshot&ls=a) gives this definition for *upshot*: ***a phenomenon that follows and is caused by some previous phenomenon***.  [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/upshot) reads: ***the result of a process or an event***.  Merriam-Webster<sup>1</sup> says quite simply, ***the final result : outcome***.  The OED<sup>2</sup> offers words such as an ***end, completion, climax, result, or conclusion***, and gives examples of it being used in positive, negative, neutral, and yet-to-determined contexts:

> *The upshot of all was, our Lord vanquished the devil*.
>   *The upshot was, that I found myself overwhelmed with debts*.
>   *Suppose a man was to talk in that manner when he's doing business, what would be the upshot?*

In short, the dictionaries are conspicuously mum about whether upshots are usually good, bad, or indifferent.

Which brings us to how the word is used in contemporary contexts: literature, journals, magazines.  To address this, I offer three links:

- [The ghost of upshots past](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20upshot%20was%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1930,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en)
- [The ghost of upshots present](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20upshot%20is%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1930,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en)
- [The ghost of upshots to come](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20upshot%20will%20be%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1930,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en)

You are welcome to scroll through those pages if you don't want to take my word for it, but the upshot is, the word is used much like it's defined.  Be it in the realm of economics, religion, law, sports, international conflict, evolution, or just the hardship of humans trying to eke out a living, some set of circumstances comes to a head – whatever falls out at the end is deemed the *upshot* of the affair.  Out the tens of thousands of possibilities found within those three links, I'll offer just *one* (a scientific use, and a very fitting one at that, since all this research has made my brain hurt):

> *And because the emissions of the various inhibitory neurons will not be in step with one another, the upshot will be inhibition that can last for a few tens of milliseconds*. (Rodney Cotterill, *Enchanted Looms: Conscious Networks in Brains and Computers*)

Which brings us to the last question that the O.P. asked: *What word is used for negative outcomes?*  Well, obviously, *upshot* will work fine, although that word can be (and is often) applied to decidedly positive contexts as well.

For alternatives, you might consider: *disaster, debacle, catastrophe, calamity, setback, or misadventure,* words with meanings that connote decidedly negative outcomes.

---

<sup>1</sup>No link given; [too many ads](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68904/meaning-of-go-down/68907#comment132861_68907).
<sup>2</sup>No link given; subscription only.

Comment: Good answer! Thank you for not making people wade through annoying spamvertising. You might reconsider withholding the OED link, though, because apart from private subscriptions, people at schools or libraries can often access them, and it would be a shame to not let them click through to a professional, spamvert-free site with a(n:) historical record of the word in English.

Comment: @tchrist: As for withholding the OED link, I just figured that anyone with the proper access credentials could simply go to the OED website and type in "upshot" ~ if they felt the need to look at the page.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the British National Corpus suggests that *upshot* does not collocate particularly with positive words. More research would be necessary to establish whether that initial impression can be substantiated.